How to carry forward URL parameters in Experience Site?
From the Email ,there is a call to action, which forwards them to my experience site with some parameters
This experience site which serves guest users has a page which requires them to fill their basic info (like name,email etc), to improve user efficiency, I need that UTM parameters are stored always, unless the whole session is not closed by the user (meaning the browser tab is not closed by the user)

So, will have a URL which forwards UTM parameters from Email to Experience Site, like:


.....?firstname=Marc&lastname=Henry

Ex:
www.test.com/Page1?firstname=Marc&lastname=Henry
www.test.com/Page2?firstname=Marc&lastname=Henry
www.test.com/Page3?firstname=Marc&lastname=Henry

How can I hold the parameters in session storage? Meaning it does not matter which page on the same site the user visits, the parameters are always appended in the end.
This is for sure possible, maybe with Script or JavaScript. But does someone have any idea how can we actually achieve it?

https://www.learnexperiencecloud.com/article/Google-Analytics-4-GA4-and-Experience-Cloud-Integration-Approaches - see Custom Integration writeup in there, that's one approach.

Could you make the Experience page that the CTA goes to be a screen flow? (then all the params are available to the screen flow as input variables)

@cropredy - Ironically on the experience site, the page where i wanna auto-fill the variables is a screen flow! But, the landing page is not that same page and that's why I need a way where it holds the variables, until session is not ended.
